# Ruby RestClient SSL cannot verify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

I was using app on two domains: 
domain.com, 
differentdomain.com

All calls from the app by RestClient was done on **differentdomain.com**. Right now i'm switching calls to domain.com because there is no need to have two different domains.

So i created subdomain **different.domain.com**. I have valid SSL certificate (with wildcard), properly set with nginx server.

When i enter **different.domain.com** in my browser i get page with valid ssl certificate. It's working ok without any bugs.

The problem is when i'm trying to call subdomain via RestClient. I'm getting this error:

```
RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Do i need update cert/key somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this SSL error indicates some issues in the certification installation such as missing `intermediate certificate`. You could verify your ssl certificate from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

If you saw "Chain Issue: Incomplete", most likely you will need to re-install your intermediate certificate again (https://community.qualys.com/thread/11685)

give it a try.